# Why this kill doesn't work in this Bash script but only outside of the script?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, kill

The following is a contrived example that demonstrates the effect and has to run with root.  It executes ping process in the background and attempts to kill it.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Ensure that there is no ping process before we begin.
killall ping

sudo ping google.com > /dev/null &
PID=$!

sleep 0.5

kill $PID
echo "Exit code of kill $PID: $?"

# Check the running ping processes. There should be no ping
# process if the above `kill $PID` worked correctly.
ps aux | grep -v grep | grep ping
```

However, the script is unable to kill the process, even if `kill`'s return code is 0.  The following is an example output.

```
$ bash test.sh
Exit code of kill 16516: 0
root     16516  0.0  0.0  14956  2212 pts/2    S    13:22   0:00 sudo ping google.com
root     16518  1.0  0.0  13112  1292 pts/2    S    13:22   0:00 ping google.com
```

I noticed that if I take out `sudo` then it properly kills it.  Why is this happening? I suspect that `sudo`'s child process messes it up somehow though.

Update 1:

Even more weird. If I execute the same `kill` command after the script, it works.

```
$ bash test.sh
Exit code of kill 16631: 0
root     16631  3.0  0.0  14956  2212 pts/2    S    13:29   0:00 sudo ping google.com
root     16633  0.0  0.0  13112  1292 pts/2    S    13:29   0:00 ping google.com
$ ps aux | grep -v grep | grep ping
root     16631  0.5  0.0  14956  2212 pts/2    S    13:29   0:00 sudo ping google.com
root     16633  0.0  0.0  13112  1292 pts/2    S    13:29   0:00 ping google.com
$ kill 16631
$ ps aux | grep -v grep | grep ping
$
$ kill 16631
-bash: kill: (16631) - No such process
$
```

Comment: Because the PID owner is root, but you are killing it as a different user. Try `sudo kill $pid`

Comment: Without the sleep, you kill `sudo` before it has a chance to start `ping`.

Comment: @thatotherguy Oh I see, that seems to explain why taking out `sleep` make it work. Though I still don't get why kill doesn't work yet...

Comment: @MattClark Not exactly what you suggested, but even if the script runs as root, still happening though. I updated the question.

Comment: Fascinating. I can reproduce this. Additionally, if I use `script -c "kill $PID"` or `setsid kill $PID`, it does kill the process as expected. `kill $PID` and `/bin/kill $PID` do not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because the controlling `sudo` process does not propagate signals coming from its own process group ([source](https://github.com/millert/sudo/blob/d5d170252a1065a6b10c3e8d0a7df1aee13a33df/src/exec_nopty.c#L160)):

```
/*
 * Do not forward signals sent by a process in the command's process
 * group, as we don't want the command to indirectly kill itself.
 * For example, this can happen with some versions of reboot that
 * call kill(-1, SIGTERM) to kill all other processes.
 */
if (USER_SIGNALED(sc->siginfo) && sc->siginfo->si_pid != 0) {
    pid_t si_pgrp = getpgid(sc->siginfo->si_pid);
    if (si_pgrp != -1) {
    if (si_pgrp == ec->ppgrp || si_pgrp == ec->cmnd_pid)
        debug_return;
    } else if (sc->siginfo->si_pid == ec->cmnd_pid) {
        debug_return;
    }
}
```

When you execute the command outside the script, you run it in a separate process group, so the signal is relayed.

Comment: Wow.  You are my hero